# How to create a new ApplicationWindow or Dialog in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I can write a declaration of ApplicationWindow or Dialog in QML:

```
MessageDialog {
   id: sampleDialog
}
```

I can use `sampleDialog.open()` to pop it or use `show` to show a ApplicationWindos. But if I need more than one Dialog or ApplicationWindow to be shown at the same time, this code cannot do this. I think there must be a QML way to create a new Dialog or ApplicationWindow dynamic to show, plz help.

Comment: Is [it answer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdeclarativedynamicobjects.html) on your question?

Comment: @t3ft3l--i Yes, thanks!